# How do I assign jQuery event handlers properly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am still learning how to use AJAX so would display a novice code here...

**I got this div (which repeats itself as a list of checkbox):**

```
<div class="updateTask fs11">
  <input type="checkbox" name="taskStatusRadio" id="taskStatus" value="<?php echo $taskId; ?>" <?php echo $done; ?> > 
  <?php _e('Task Done', 'sagive'); ?>
</div>
```

**Which activates this:**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.updateTask').click(function () {

        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'action_update_task',
            task_id: $("input[name=taskStatusRadio]:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get()

        }, function(data) {

            // USE DATA RETURNED //////////
            var $response   = $(data);
            var message     = $response.filter('div#message').html();
            var taskid      = $response.filter('div#taskid').html();        

            // SUCCESS RESPOND //////////
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#success ul li').append(message + taskid);
                $('#success').fadeIn();
                $('#success').css("display", "block");              
            }, 1000);   

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#success ul li').empty();
                $('#success').fadeIn();
                $('#success').css("display", "none");               
            }, 30000);


            hideTask = "#" + taskid;
            $(hideTask).hide("slow");

            hideTask = '';

        });
    });
});
```

**And uses this php file:**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-update-task', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ajaxLoops/ajax-update_task.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-update-task', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl

add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_update_task', 'ajax_update_task' ); // ajax for logged in users
function ajax_update_task() {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $task_user = $current_user->display_name;
    if($taskUser == '') {$taskUser = $current_user->user_login;}

    $task_id = $_POST["task_id"];
    $task_id = $task_id[0];
    $task_status = 'done';
    $task_title = get_the_title($task_id);
    $task_title = mb_substr($task_title, 0 ,35).'...';

    update_post_meta($task_id, '_sagive_task_radio_selector', $task_status);
    update_post_meta($task_id, '_sagive_task_user_changed', $task_user);

    echo '<div id="message">'.__('The task: ', 'sagive').$task_title.__('Was Marked Completed!', 'sagive').'</div>';
    echo '<div id="taskid">'.$task_id.'</div>';

    die(); // stop executing script
}
```

It all works fine the first time. But the second checkbox I mark after the first one disappears as expected does nothing. It doesn't activate the php script and doesn't return a response.

Since I'm still new using AJAX, I would appreciate an example using my code or a good example with explanation.

**Revision 1:**
This is the structure of the page where the checkboxes are at
[image]

Comment: Perhaps to downvoter would like to provide some constructive criticism/advice?

Comment: Does the checkbox itself have an event tied to it? If so, it's possible that the checkbox is halting propagation, you generally want the event to be on the top-most element

Comment: Your current jQuery selector for the click event handler is for this `<div>` tag. Is that what you want or do you want the event handler bound to the check boxes in the divs with class of "updateTask"  ?

Comment: thanks jon p ;) - i think the down vote is automatic since i first submitted it on WORDPRESS.stackexchange...   I choose the div because its a page with a lot of checkboxes each with its own value and I didn't know how to say in jQuery "when_clicking_this_id" <--- since its might be one out of a hundred checkboxes... so I surrounded it by a div... Is that the wrong way?  i would add an image to display the page structre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem comes from your selector :

```
$("input[name=taskStatusRadio]:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get();
```

which returns all the `taskStatusRadio` input checked and not just the one you click.

Your php script receive all the taskid checked in an array an pick the first one to treat it and send a response.

So the first time, it's ok, you just have one checkbox checked. But when you check a second checkbox, all checked taskid will be send and only the `$_POST["task_id"][0]` will be treated.

Same response from your php script and no change in the front view.

So, i think, you just have to modify a little bit your code, to post only taskid of the checkbox you click on it.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // we listen only the checkbox, not the div click action
    $(':checkbox', '.updateTask').click(function () {
        // if the checkbox is checked
        if ($(this).attr('checked') == "checked") {

            $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
                  action: 'action_update_task',
                  task_id: $(this).val() }, 
                  function(data) {

                      // SUCCESS RESPOND //////////
                      setTimeout(function() {
                          $('#success ul li').append( $(data).html());
                          $('#success').fadeIn();
                          $('#success').css("display", "block");              
                          }, 1000);   

                      setTimeout(function() {
                          $('#success ul li').empty();
                          $('#success').fadeIn();
                          $('#success').css("display", "none");               
                          }, 30000);

                      // we hide the checkbox
                      $(this).hide("slow");
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

And because of this change in the front javascript, we have to simplify your php script like this :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-update-task', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ajaxLoops/ajax-update_task.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-update-task', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl

add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_update_task', 'ajax_update_task' ); // ajax for logged in users
function ajax_update_task() {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $task_user = $current_user->display_name;
    if($taskUser == '') {$taskUser = $current_user->user_login;}

    $task_id = $_POST["task_id"];
    $task_status = 'done';
    $task_title = get_the_title($task_id);
    $task_title = mb_substr($task_title, 0 ,35).'...';

    update_post_meta($task_id, '_sagive_task_radio_selector', $task_status);
    update_post_meta($task_id, '_sagive_task_user_changed', $task_user);

    //  Note : now we send the message directly well-formed with the task_id
    echo __('The task: ', 'sagive').$task_title.__('Was Marked   Completed!', 'sagive'). $task_id;

    die(); // stop executing script
}
```

I hope my answer will solve your problem ;)

ps: i apologize for my poor english...

Comment: Yeeee!!! it works - thanks mate & for the explenation, helped me understand the problem :)